# Discord.py and emojis within an embed

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have created a Discord.py bot that responds to a command with an embed. However, I'm having trouble having the bot include custom emojis within the embed message. This is what I have so far -

```
        if message.content.find("$opendd") != -1:
            message.delete()
            embed = discord.Embed(title="We Are Open", description="**HOW CAN YOU PAY?** \n - <:pp:700719821829963927> PayPal\n - <:cashapp:700719887961817109> CashApp\n - <:btc:700719874057699408> Bitcoin\n - :venmo: <venmo:700720856489394257> Venmo", color=0x183e7c)
            embed.set_footer("Opened by" + "")
            await message.channel.send("@here",embed=embed)
```

However, the embed seems to ignore the Emoji ID and just prints out the emoji in plaintext as :cashapp: or :btc:. Any fix to this?

Answer (score 0):

at first I noticed this `:venmo: <venmo:700720856489394257>` something seems not right here!
You might wanna edit this to `<:venmo:700720856489394257>`

Further more, are you sure the bot is in the server where the emojis are from?
In order for this to work the bot has to be in the server with the emojis.